# Forcing Node.js modules to follow an interface

Tags: javascript, node.js, interface, adapter, node-modules

I have a simple generic DB interface and want to force my DB adapters to follow that interface. So, both `db.js` and `fake_mongo_adapter.js` should have the same functions' names and params, like this:

```
db.init(client, options, callback)
db.get(client, query, callback)
```

Now I'm doing it with Underscore's `extend` function and throwing exceptions if there is no needed function.

Is it ok?

Is there any other approaches to force several Node.js modules to follow the one contract?

*server.js, Entry point*

```
var _ = require('underscore');
var mongoose = require('mongoose'); // Adaptee

var db = require('./db');
var fake_mongodb_adapter_raw = require('./fake_mongodb_adapter');

var fake_mongodb_adapter = _.extend({}, db);
fake_mongodb_adapter = _.extend(fake_mongodb_adapter, fake_mongodb_adapter_raw);

mongoose.connect('connection string');
fake_mongodb_adapter.init(mongoose, options, function run_app(err, person_model) {
    fake_mongodb_adapter.get(person_model, { _id: '1234' }, function (err, found_person) {
        console.log('found person: ' + JSON.stringify(found_person));
    });
});
```

*db.js, Generic DB interface used by the client, it shouldn't be changed.*

```
module.exports = {
    init: init,
    get: get
};

function init(client, options, callback) {
    throw new Error('Function "init" not implemented');
}

function get(client, query, callback) {
    throw new Error('Function "get" not implemented');
}
```

*fake_mongodb_adapter.js*

```
module.exports = {
    init: init,
    get: get
};

function init(client, options, callback) {
    console.log('initialized fake MongoDB adapter');
    return callback(null);
}

function get(client, query, callback) {
    var person = { id: '1234', name: 'Mary' };
    return callback(null, person);
}
```